# cygwin help: Xlib: connection to "ip:0.0" refused by server

Tags: cygwin, xserver, xauth

I followed cygwin user guide as below:
http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using-remote-apps.html

on windows xp, i started Cygwin/X->XWin server,

```
EXPORT DISPLAY=:0.0
ssh -Y user@ip
```

i saw below warning

```
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
```

after login, i typed
bash-3.00$ xclock &
[1] 26962
bash-3.00$ Xlib: connection to "clientip:0.0" refused by server
Xlib: No protocol specified

Error: Can't open display: clientip:0.0

can anyone help?

Comment: Is "clientip" the Cygwin machine or the other one? (I have to ask because people sometimes get confused about the words "client" and "server" with X, thinking that the machine on their desk can't be the "server" - it is!)

Comment: the ""clientip:0.0" i'm referring to the windows xp machine where i install my cygwin and xserver software.

Comment: Can you run "xauth list" locally on the Cygwin machine?

Comment: i run the command but got nothing

Comment: what command line did you use to start Cygwin/X?

Comment: i click 'start->programs->cygwinx->xwin server';   when i try to input 'startxwin', it said 'startxwin: Another X server instance is running on DISPLAY :0
: Resource temporarily unavailable';  i also tried startx and then do ssh -Y, but the result is the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4300/discussion-between-alan-curry-and-hetaoblog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a chat session some more evidence was examined, and this conclusion was reached:

> yes, sometime ago, i added export DISPLAY=mywindowsip:0.0 in my shell rc file
>   so this was executed everytime when i ssh to the shell

The ssh-forwarded DISPLAY variable was being obliterated, and the unix machine was making unauthorized connections directly to the cygwin X server.